# rpmbuild command won't find the build directory

Tags: rpm, packaging, yum

I am trying to install some config files using an rpm package and am having trouble with the final build step. I have tried using a lot of different variable combinations but I keep getting file not found errors. It appears to be a problem with where rpmbuild is unpacking (or not unpacking) files and where it anticipates those files. Right now I have a spec file that looks like this:

```
Summary: My Package
Name: my-package
Version: 1.1
Release: Public
Group: Applications/System
License: Public
Requires: collectd
Source: sources.tar.gz 

%prep
%setup

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/


# list files owned by the package here
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%config /etc/collectd/collectd.conf.custom
%config /etc/collectd/collectd.d/http.conf
%config /etc/collectd/collectd.d/csv.conf
/usr/local/bin/myfile.py
/usr/local/bin/my-package

%post
ln -sf /etc/collectd.conf.custom /etc/collectd.conf
```

I currently get output which looks like this:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m5Qvz9
+ umask 022
+ cd ./BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /BUILD
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m5Qvz9: line 31: cd: /BUILD: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m5Qvz9 (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m5Qvz9 (%prep)
```

I'm not sure why it is trying to `cd` into the `/BUILD` directory twice.

If I leave out the `%setup` line I get the following output:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.3c5as7
+ umask 022
+ cd ./BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.FAF3wq
+ umask 022
+ cd ./BUILD
+ '[' ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64
++ dirname ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64
+ mkdir -p ./BUILDROOT
+ mkdir ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ mkdir -p ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd/
+ mkdir -p ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/usr/bin/
+ mkdir -p ./BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/usr/bin/collectd.conf.d/
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64
error: File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.conf.custom
error: File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.d/http.conf
error: File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.d/csv.conf
error: File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/usr/local/bin/myfile.py
error: File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/usr/local/bin/my-package


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.conf.custom
    File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.d/http.conf
    File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.d/csv.conf
    File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/usr/local/bin/myfile.py
    File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/usr/local/bin/my-package
```

Which I would expect after remove `%setup` as it no longer unpacks the source. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore those two "cd", it is likely in different process. So what actually matter is

```
cd /BUILD
```

And I assume that this directory indeed does not exists. It is set by %_topdir macro. It is highly recommended to put

```
%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
```

in  ~/.rpmmacros file. Then you will need to create several directories in ~/rpmbuild. You can run command "rpmdev-setuptree" (from package rpmdevtools) which will create it for you.

**Edit:**

Additionaly this line:

```
error: File not found: /BUILDROOT/my-package-1.1-Public.x86_64/etc/collectd.conf.custom
```

means that rpmbuild is unable to find this file in buildroot while you list it in %files section. You should put something like this in %install section:

```
cp -a collectd.conf.custom %{buildroot}/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.custom
```

if this file is part of your tar.gz file. Or use any other shell command which create that file on that location. Similarly for all files, which report rpmbuild as missing.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.rpmmacros` file, is it possible that it would be installed somewhere else?

Comment: Also the `/BUILD` at the `%_topdir` does seem to exist. If I strip my directory contents down to just `/SOURCES` and `/SPECS` (where my files are) rpmbuild will make the other directories including `/BUILD`. This is when I use the command `rpmbuild -bb -D '_topdir .' SPECS/my-package.spec`